# Ads admob in android app using Youtube API?

Tags: android, youtube, admob

I have created an android application.

In my app, i have used youtube api to play video using video_id, and now i want to know can i integrate Admob Ads in this app?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: yes, you can integrate.

Comment: Unfortunately, your question in the current form is not a good fit. SO is for concrete questions. If you have problems getting this to work, please add your non-working code to the question and describe as precisely as possible what does not work and how it fails.

Answer (score 2):

You can integrate admob ads in your application but when you will submit it at play store. It will be rejected by google because it is against their policy for an app which generates revenue parallely with youtube. I have faced this situation and my app was rejected so i had to remove admob to get it on playstore.

Comment: In my case that app was blocked by admob. My app is still on play store but ads are disabled by admob